# How to add auto incrementing number field in aggregation query?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sorting, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have used the query shown here to generate new field using `$setWindowFields`, but it's causing a memory issue.

I need a new field which should give numerical incrementing values.

This query causes memory issues:

```
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "employee",
      localField: "empId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "employee",
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$employee",
    },
  },

  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "student",
      localField: "studentId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "student",
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$student",
    },
  },
  {
    $setWindowFields: {
      sortBy: {
        _id: 1,
      },
      output: {
        incNum: {
          $documentNumber: {},
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      incNum: {
        $toString: "$incNum",
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      incNum: "$incNum",
    },
  },
```

Comment: Can you add some source sample documents and an example of what you want the output to be please?

Comment: I want to output a new field in output , as numeric field start from 1.Ex :[{id:123,name:"test",incField:1},{id:1232,name:"test",incField:2},{id:1233,name:"test",incField:3}...]

Comment: Thank you. Are you able to edit the question to add some sample document as well as the desired document output because if you are having memory issues it will be able to see where your aggregation can be optimised. It's difficult with only a narrow view of the problem. Sample data helps see the whole picture. I appreciate you may have to redact or obfuscate sensitive data.

Comment: I updated my query in above question

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your source data I am going to go out on a limb and assume based on what you've said that you just want to add an incremental value to each document after the sort. In which case you can use `$count` within the `$setWindowFields` aggregation stage. Used without a partition it will just count the number of documents since you are not partitioning them and the value will be increased on each document.

Hopefully this helps:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $setWindowFields: {
      sortBy: {
        _id: 1
      },
      output: {
        incField: {
          $count: {},
          window: {
            documents: [
              "unbounded",
              "current"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See [HERE](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aiWRUIMg75B) for a working example with some basic sample data.

Comment: Hi jQueeny, Thank you very much for your answer. Actually due to sort I am facing memory issue. so is it possible without using sort i can perform count the number of documents  and the value will be increased on each document

Comment: `$setWindowFields` needs a sort. I assume the `employee` and `student` lookups produce a lot of documents after the unwind stages? `$sort` is subject to the 100 megabyte memory usage limit so yes you will have issues with large dataset.

Comment: yes , employee and student produces a lot of data, and Sort exceeding memory limit. is there any other way to generate numbers for incField ?

Comment: What version of mongodb are you using? Starting in MongoDB 6.0, pipeline stages that require more than 100 megabytes of memory to execute write temporary files to disk by default. In earlier verisons of MongoDB, you must pass { allowDiskUse: true } to individual find and aggregate commands to enable this behavior. See [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#-sort-and-memory-restrictions).

Comment: I am using mongo version 6.0

Comment: Do the ids used in the sort have an index? I presume they do? Have you tried passing in `{ allowDiskUse: true }` after the aggregation e.g `aggregate([...], { allowDiskUse: true })`

Comment: localField: "empId"  has Index  called empId_1

Comment: I am running query in mongo compass aggregation

Comment: This sounds like a compass limitation. Run the query in the mongosh shell.